# MySQL - IF statement

Tags: mysql

My code :

```
SELECT * FROM `invoices` WHERE
( 
   user_id = 3 AND status="online"
)
```

But the `admin id = 1 (user_id=1)`

How can I allow the admin to see the data?

Comment: What _But the admin id = 1 (user_id=1)_ is supposed to mean?

Comment: and why is the where clause in brackets?

Comment: @OP: do you want to query for invoices of specific user or the admin user?

Comment: @Ravinder : when the user login to system i need to show his invoices and when the admin login see all invoices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case you need two SQL queries - one for regular users, another one for admins. In the query for admins just remove the `where` clause.
Your application logic (the one that controls SQL queries) should determine the user role and based on the role should use the relevant SQL query.